# How to fix System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.Element(...) returned null

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, linq

I am Trying to Write and Read data to and From XML file, Writing is working fine but while reading I am getting System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.Element(...) returned null. error. I am First taking the input from the user through form saving it in XML and then fetching the data from XML and displaying it in listview

Writing code

```
private void Btn_addproduct_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            i++;
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("C:\\Users\\karam\\source\\repos\\KanbanBoard\\bin\\Debug\\tester.xml");
            doc.Root.Add(new XElement("Project",
                new XElement("ProjectId", i),
                new XElement("ProjectTitle", projectTitle.Text),
                new XElement("ProjectDescription", projectDescription.Text),
                new XElement("StartDate", startDate.Text),
                new XElement("EndDate", endDate.Text),
                new XElement("ToDoLimit", toDoLimit.Text),
                new XElement("WorkInProgressLimit", workInProgressLimit.Text),
                new XElement("DoneLimit", doneLimit.Text)
                ));
            doc.Save("C:\\Users\\karam\\source\\repos\\KanbanBoard\\bin\\Debug\\tester.xml");
        }
```

Reading Code

```
 private void Btn_productlist_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("C:\\Users\\karam\\source\\repos\\KanbanBoard\\bin\\Debug\\tester.xml");
            var result=doc.Descendants("Projects").Select(x=>new
            {
                projectid = x.Element("ProjectId").Value,
                projecttitle = x.Element("ProjectTitle").Value,
                projectdescription = x.Element("ProjectDescription").Value,
                startdate = x.Element("StartDate").Value,
                enddate = x.Element("EndDate").Value,
                todolimit = x.Element("ToDoLimit").Value,
                workinprogresslimit = x.Element("WorkInProgressLimit").Value,
                donelimit = x.Element("DoneLimit").Value,
            });


            Projectlistview.ItemsSource = result;

        }
```

Comment: You are writing to a ‘Project’ element but reading from ‘Projects’

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Descendants(name)` method returns a collection of the descendant elements for the given document. (Only the elements that have a matching name will be included in the collection)

It is giving `null` because it couldn't find an element having name `Projects`.

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("C:\\Users\\karam\\source\\repos\\KanbanBoard\\bin\\Debug\\tester.xml");
 var result = doc.Descendants("Projects").Select(x => new //Should be Project
 //rest of the code
```